# How to do a Close Confirmation with a Xamarin Forms mac App?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` application for `iOS, Android,` and now hopefully Mac.  I made all the adjustments for the UI to look great on Mac.  Submitted it for approval where it was rejected because the user can close the window while the app and menu bar is still running.  So I figure I would just add a confirmation pop-up asking if they want to exit the app when they try to close the window.

- OK = Terminate the App.
- Cancel = Keep the window open.

I find lots of articles on how to handle this with a `Xamarin.Mac` app, but nothing on how to handle `Xamarin.Forms` on Mac.  The `FormsApplicationDelegate` does not give access to the View Controller or the Window Delegate in order to override the `WindowShouldClose` method.  I found that I can use `NSAlert` to do the pop-up which works great.  Now I cannot find anything on what to do when the user responds. Open to suggestions.

```
 private void Window_WillClose(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        NSNotification senderNotification = ((NSNotification)sender); 
        NSWindow closingWindow = (NSWindow)senderNotification.Object;

        var confirmation = new NSAlert()
        {
            AlertStyle = NSAlertStyle.Warning,
            InformativeText = "Are you sure you want to exit the App?",
            MessageText = "Exit?"
        };
        confirmation.AddButton("OK");
        confirmation.AddButton("Cancel");
        var result = confirmation.RunModal();

        if (result == 1001)
        {
            //Cancel closing the window
        }
        else
        {
            //terminate the app
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. How can you be sure that after users confirms to close app  menu bar wont be running? I think you should rather focus to prevent user from closing the app when it initialises, or initialise menu bar after app is initialised?

Comment: initializing is not the issue.  Everything loads fine, initializes fine, and looks great.  The issue is when the user wants to exit the app.  Yes, I need to make sure that the menu bar won't be running when they close the window.  That is the question.  How do you completely terminate the app with the Window.WillClose event?

Comment: Why not to use OnSleep() event handler??

Comment: Looking for the code that would either terminate the app or stop the window from closing. Thx.

Comment: When your app is background and user wants to close it your code cannot be running. I guess the problem is when your app goes to the background, so in this case you use OnSleep(). Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks..I appreciate the response, but not sure how that solves this question.  The user is closing the active Window in a single Window App.  I need to stop the app or cancel the closing of the window. Chad covers it here for Xamarin.Mac, but this does not work with a Xamarin.Forms app.  http://chadkuehn.com/cancelabort-a-closing-window-in-xamarin-mac/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I did find a solution.  Here is what officially passed Apple's review.  It requires that n menu action is linked as "New Window".  It keeps tracks of the open windows and when there is only one left, it prompts to close the app.  If the user closes all the windows and keeps the app running, they have the option to open a new window in the menu.

```
 [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public NSWindow window;
        private bool closeApp;
        private List<NSWindow> openWindows;
        public override NSWindow MainWindow
        {
            get { return window; }
        }


        public AppDelegate()
        {
            this.closeApp = false;
            this.openWindows = new List<NSWindow>();
            createNewWindow();
        }

        [Action("newWindow:")]
        public void newWindow(NSObject sender)
        {

            createNewWindow();
            this.window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(sender);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            base.DidFinishLaunching(null);

        }

        private void createNewWindow()
        {
            var style = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;
            var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
            window = new MainWindow(rect, style, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false);
            window.Title = "MyApp"; // choose your own Title here
            window.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
            window.WillClose += Window_WillClose;
            openWindows.Add(window);
        }

        private void Window_WillClose(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            openWindows.Remove((NSWindow)((NSNotification)sender).Object);
            if (openWindows.Count == 0)
            {
                var confirmation = new NSAlert()
                {
                    AlertStyle = NSAlertStyle.Warning,
                    InformativeText = "Do you want to exit the app?",
                    MessageText = "Exit?"
                };
                confirmation.AddButton("Yes");
                confirmation.AddButton("No");
                var result = confirmation.RunModal();

                if (result == 1001)
                {
                    this.closeApp = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //terminate the app
                    this.closeApp = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public override bool ApplicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(NSApplication sender)
        {
            return closeApp;
        }

        public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
        {
            Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            base.DidFinishLaunching(notification);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But what about where the ViewModel is the object that needs to determine if the app should close or not? I can't workout how to get to that data from `MainWindow`.

Comment: I used the above code. I am getting the following error 

Foundation.ObjCException: NSInternalInconsistencyException: Modal session cannot be run during application termination

I tried disposing of the confirmation modal - still the same error. What could be the issue?