# How to use DisplayAlert when closing the main window

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have this button in XAML:

```
<Button
    x:Name="UpdateButton"
    Padding="10"
    Command="{Binding SaveAndUpdateCommand}"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Text="Save and Update"
    VerticalOptions="End" />
```

In the code behind I have set up the binding command like this:

```
SaveAndUpdateCommand = new Command(OnSaveAndUpdate, canExecute: () => { return IsDirty; });
```

The system operates and when changes are made to the GUI the button enables. Then after performing a save the button disables.

But I wanted to go one step further and use `DisplayAlert` if `IsDirty` was `true` when the user tried closing the window with the X (upper left).

My first idea was to override `OnDisappearing` and make it `async`. It correctly showed the popup message but thereafter would never close the window any more. I did some research and quickly found out that it was a bad idea to show popup windows from this override.

I am still not sure what is the simplest way to handle this issue in the Xamarin.Forms app on the macOS platform. To summarise:

```
User tries to close the main app window with X at top left
    if IsDirty is true
        Show alert (yes/no) and get response
        if yes then save and continue closing
        if no then just continue closing
```

Ideally it would also offer Cancel as a way to abort closing.

Comment: Found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212987/how-to-do-a-close-confirmation-with-a-xamarin-forms-mac-app and researching it to see if it answers mine.

Comment: The linked answer does help I don't think (?). It refers to making changes in my macOS AppDelegate, which I kind of understand, but the `IsDirty` logic etc is in the pages ViewModel which we don't have access to in the AppDelegate.